# Remove and add back

Tags: jquery, dom, append

I am new to jquery and I am trying something that seems straight forward but I can not make it work.

```
function register() {
    $("#main_content").load("kpp/register.php");
    var cacheDom = "";
    cacheDom = $('#col3');
    $('#col3').append(cacheDom);
};

function match_up() {
    $("#col3").remove();
    $("kpp_border").removeClass();
    $("#main_content").load("kpp/match_up.php");
};
```

Both these functions are triggered onclick.  but when I go from match_up to register #col3 does not come back.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
};

Comment: `$('#col3').append($('#col3')` doesn't make sense in the register method.  An element cannot be a child of itself.

Comment: And once the col3 is removed from the dom, it will not be available any longer to be found.

Comment: By the time you run `cacheDom = $('#col3')` this element is non-existent, there's nothing to cache and, only a reference to the element would be cached anyway. .. Perhaps you want to look at `.detach()` or `.clone()` methods.

Comment: Thank you I will look at .clone